# Need to Optimize SQL statement for NOT EXISTS check for multiple columns

Tags: multiple-columns, exists

Below is the exact code that need to optimize. Please assist.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
            FROM Table1
            WHERE Clientid = 1111
                  AND
                  Objectid IN ( SELECT Objectid
                                FROM Table1
                                WHERE clientid = 5555
                              )
                  AND
                  Fieldid IN ( SELECT Fieldid
                               FROM Table1
                               WHERE clientid = 5555
                             )
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.

The check need to put to control the rows to be inserted in table. So I extended my Insert query as follow:

Insert into table 
Select col2, col3, col4 from table t1 where not exists ( select * from table t2 t1.col2= t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3 )

pheww...